# How do I upload my own custom zip of a deployment?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I'm trying to use an existing setup/deployment, however it has a failure and hence I thought I'd try fix it by creating my own "deployment".

I can't figure out how to do this though.

I just get a page of **"There are no solutions yet. Contact your admin for status on the catalogue."**
[image]

I followed the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/private-catalog/docs/create-catalog

However at step 3 - there is no "manage solutions" button...

I HAVE added the "catalogue admin" + "catalogue manager" roles to my user.

Why am I not getting this button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three prerequisites to use Private Catalogues:

- You must have a Google Cloud organization and access to the organization.
- You must have the administrator role for your Google Cloud organization.
- You must have the Catalog admin role for Private Catalog.

Perhaps you are only missing the first one:
Organizations are only available for GSuite and Cloud Identity customers: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization

---

**Edit:** [here](https://cloud.google.com/private-catalog/docs/quickstart-private-catalog) is a better quickstart guide for using Private Catalogues: